# AngularJS md-dialog display white text and buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to use a md-dialog to ask the user to confirm the use of a buy function:

HTML

```
<md-button ng-click="showConfirm($event, 'buy')"  style="background-color: #2196f3; width:45%; "><b>BUY NOW</b></md-button>
```

and JS

```
$scope.status = '  ';
  $scope.customFullscreen = $mdMedia('xs') || $mdMedia('sm');
  $scope.showConfirm = function(ev, type) {
// Appending dialog to document.body to cover sidenav in docs app
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
      .title('WOULD YOU LIKE TO BUY/SELL NOW?')
      .textContent('This will place a market order and charge a 1% Luno fee.')
      .ariaLabel('Lucky day')
      .targetEvent(ev)
      .ok('Confirm')
      .cancel('Decline');
  $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(){
    if (type === "buy") {
      $scope.buy(0,true);
    } else {
      $scope.sell(0,true);
    }
  });
}
```

The dialog works fine, buys and sells on confirmation, but the style is messed up, displaying the title, ok and cancel as white so you cant see it. Only the textContent is black. As I understand it, it is supposed to get it's style from the default stuff, so why doesnt it look like the dialog that was on the Angular demo page?

Comment: looks like your missing a CSS file.

Comment: Which would that be?

Comment: check on the angular demo page, if it doesn't have instructions, check the view page source to see if there are any CSS files that they have included for the same page and you have not.

Comment: There are not CSS files linked which I can see https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

Comment: you can style them using the classes `md-confirm-button` and `md-cancel-button`. I suggest you take a basic course on angular [here](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/105/How-to-Install-Angular-5-(Tutorial)) to see how things are set up. I think you have a problem in your components scss.

Comment: No problem, I'm not an angular user so unfortunately I can't help you precisely. Good luck :)

Comment: So basically I switched from a mdConfirm dialog to a mdAdvanced one. You can easily change the CSS of the mdAdvanced one. That solved my problem. But thanks again Ivan!

Comment: your welcome, glad you solved it.